# Why was "the room" not used in "Prices vary according to the type of room you require"?

Tags: definite-article, determiners

The sentence below is an example sentence from Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary for the entry for the verb "vary".
I wonder why **the room** was not used and why just **room** was used here.
As "room" here is a space that somebody specifically requires, I think it can be regarded as a specified noun.

> Prices vary according to the type of **room** you require.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think we don't use an article there because we already have one for the whole noun phrase, **the type of room**.  *type* refers to a specific type; *room* doesn't refer to a specific room, but any room you might get.  But it's a good question.

Comment: @stangdon Thank you for the comment. It helps me understand it a lot, but I do not feel very sure about it as I feel like getting an answer in a grammatical sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the accent is on "the type". The room is just adding more meaning to the type - together they work as an expression: **"the type of room"**.

Since the "room" is used in the most generic way, a definite article would not fit.

---

On the other hand, you can have **"the type of the room"** as well, in a different context.

Consider this:

> You will be in room XZ. **The type of the room** does not allow you to smoke inside.

In this example, the room is known, and the sentence is built around that specific room, so the definite article is needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. This clears up my confusion.